# numbers on x-axis graph in Microsoft Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a problem with a graph in Excel. Here is how it looks like

[image: x axis start from 0 to 10]

The problem is that I need the x-axis to start from 0 to 10

I am using Excel 2007. Basically, what I need is U=f(alpha)

Comment: Right click on the X axis for those kinds of controls.

Answer (score 1):

- Right-click on the x-axis to bring up the axis control menus.
- Select 'Format axis'
- In 'Axis Options' you can set your minimum and maximum boundaries for the axis (see below).  Be sure to select 'Fixed' so you can enter your values for the minimum and maximum values (and intervals if so desired).

[image]

[Image source](http://peltiertech.com/changes-to-charting-in-excel-2007/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the type of graph to X-Y Scatter.

Select the graph and then Format, Chart. Change to X-Y Scatter and click OK. It should then rearrange the x-axis.